# Send variable from one class to another continuously

Tags: flutter

I have a class where the connection to Strophe takes place and I am continuously receiving incoming messages. I want that every time a new message arrives, it is sent to the other class that generates the chat interface to show the message on the screen. But I do not know how to do it.

This is the function that receives the messages. What I want is to send `message` to the other class every time a new message arrives.

```
onMessage(xml.XmlElement msg) {
    var to = msg.getAttribute('to');
    var from = msg.getAttribute('from');
    var type = msg.getAttribute('type');
    List<xml.XmlElement> body = msg.findElements('body').toList();

    var now = new DateTime.now();

    NewMessage message = NewMessage();
    message.from = from;
    message.fecha = now.toString();
    message.body = body.map((node) => node.text).elementAt(0);
    message.read = false;

    // we must return true to keep the handler alive.
    // returning false would remove it after it finishes.

    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Stream in this case

Simple Example:

```
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  //
  // Initialize a "Single-Subscription" Stream controller
  //
  final StreamController ctrl = StreamController();

  //
  // Initialize a single listener which simply prints the data
  // as soon as it receives it
  //
  final StreamSubscription subscription = ctrl.stream.listen((data) => print('$data'));

  //
  // We here add the data that will flow inside the stream
  //
  ctrl.sink.add('my name');
  ctrl.sink.add(1234);
  ctrl.sink.add({'a': 'element A', 'b': 'element B'});
  ctrl.sink.add(123.45);

  //
  // We release the StreamController
  //
  ctrl.close();
}
```

the BLoC pattern will be best for you.
[BLoC Pattern](https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/08/reactive-programming---streams---bloc/)